# Database Design with regard to my business logic

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

i am building an invoicing application consisting of following business logic.

> **a)** Place a new order for customer. (an order is a group of three
>   related components, estimate, invoice and purchaseorder)
>
> **b)** After placing an order a new estimate can be generated. an order
>   will have only one estimate.(An estimate consist of item details)
>
> **c)** With reference to an estimate of the order. an invoice can be
>   generated. an invoice qualify for the discount of price. apart from
>   item details, an invoice consist of some expenses.an order can contain
>   only one invoice
>
> **d)** with reference to an invoice of the order, PurchaseOrder can be
>   generated. PurchaseOrder consist of item information about vendor
>   purchase. an order can contain multiple PurchaseOrder.

here is the database table design i have come up with.

[image]

while all look good, i am having difficulty deciding where to store the items list that belongs to particular estimate, invoice or purchaseorder of the order.

i had thought of several solution.

> **Approach A :** create different tables for item list for each. (estimate, invoice and purchase order)
>   **table :** `estimate_item` , `invoice_item` , `purchaseorder_item`.(this tables contains columns similar to that of
>   order_item in above image).
>   **problem:** problem with this approach is all the three tables consist of identical columns storing identical information, the only
>   difference is foreign key that will be stored.
>
> **Approach B:** create one item list table `order_item`
>   **tablename:** `order_item`
>   **problem:** not sure what to store as foreign key in this table since the foreign key can be from three different table. i thought of few
>   way of handling foreign keys in this table as follows.
>
> **1)foreignKey table reference column:** type (example values: estimate, invoice, purchaseorder) foreignKey column: type_id(consist
>   of foreignKey of any of three tables)
>  **problem:** i am using naming
>   convention for column names for example column name ending with `tablename_id` defines the foreign key. and this method violate the rules.
>
> **2) foreignKeyColumn:** `order_id` , `estimate_id` , `invoice_id` ,
>   `purchaseorder_id`.
>  **problem:** unnecessary foreign key columns
>   defined.

i want to know how should i store the foreign key in `order_item` table so that it identifies the order and estimate/invoice/purchaseorder it belongs too.

the relationship for tables are:

> `id` is the primary key for all the tables

```
table name: order relates to (contact, estimate, invoice, shipment) tables.
column name: contact_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the contact table)).
column name: estimate_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the estimate table)).
column name: invoice_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the invoice table)).
column name: shipment_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the shipment table)).

tablename: purchaseorder (this have one to many relationship with order table)
column name: order_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the order table)).
column name: contact_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the contact table)).
```

the question is about how to go with the storing of foreign keys in order_item table.

Thank you.

**Update 1:**

Please note that each table `estimate` , `invoice`  and `purchaseorder` will have item of it's own and having no relation to each other.

Comment: Surely `order_item` references the associated `order` which in turn references the associated `invoice`, `estimate` and/or `purchaseorder`?  Why do you need to reference the latter tables from each `order_item`?

Comment: @eggyal sorry my bad, i uploaded the wrong image. that was just the thought process i was going onto. and updated the columns with all the fields. updated my image now

Comment: But my point remains... you have multiple `order_item` referencing each `order`, which in turn references associated `invoice`, `estimate` and/or `purchaseorder` as appropriate, no?  What's the problem (except the arrows in your ERD)?

Comment: yes, each order consist of multiple items hence multiple order_item, i have to relate the `order_item` to `invoice` , `estimate` , `purchaseorder` which in turn belongs to an order.

Comment: I feel like we're going in circles.  My first question asked "**Why do you need to reference the latter tables from each `order_item`** [given that the `order_item` references an `order` which in turn references those tables]"?  Are you suggesting that items in the *same* order might relate to *different* `invoice`, `estimate` or `purchaseorder`?  I think you're attempting to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: it is because, each `invoices`, `estimate` and `purchaseorder` consist of different items. that means all three tables will have items of its own. the items of estimate have nothing to do with items of invoice or purchase order. and so on.

Comment: I think you should name 'id' in estimate table named what it is, which is 'estimate_id'.  usually when you join you do 'where A.estimate_id = B.estimate_id".  meaning the names of the id's are the same.  If you have mmany more tables, knowing what 'id' is becomes hard.  the diagram should tell you these relationships, it should make them clear.

Comment: agreed, the diagram is not clear since i am not so good at designing db i am learning, the above naming convention is taken from doctrine orm and zend framework recommends the same too. which i am using both.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure how the relations happen.  for instance, you have 'estimate' pointing to 'order item' but I don't see what key you have to make that join (or look-up).  as another 'order' points to 'estimate' but how are those two joined?  I dont see any shared attributes that both those entities have.

I'm assuming 'id' is just something to make rows in each particular table unique, but are not id's that have value to the application.  so, I would think you' need to carry estimate.reference number into the 'order item' table.  This is just a cursory comment.

also, would hep for clarity if keys were listed first.  so in 'order item' you have attribute 'order id' (which appears to be an FK) buried in the end of the list of other attributes.  makes this hard to read.

Comment: updated the image as i have upload the wrong image earlier. i have been using ming mapping tool. ill update the question with what relation does each table consist to another.

Comment: oh ok got it.  thanks that would help me look at this closer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each document associated with an order (i.e. an `estimate`, `purchaseorder` and/or `invoice`) might contain a different list of items.

If that is the case, I would probably create a `Documents` table along the following lines:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents (
  DocumentId   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderId      INT NOT NULL,
  -- you can move any fields common to all document types here
  -- e.g. date created, reference #, etc.
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderId) REFERENCES order (id)
);
```

And then your `order_item`, `estimate`, `purchaseorder` and `invoice` tables all reference their associated entry in this table:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename]
  ADD COLUMN DocumentId INT NOT NULL,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (DocumentId) REFERENCES Documents (DocumentId)
);
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: it would be nice if the key names were the same across tables.  for instance he says : estimate_id (foreign key(referring to id column of the estimate table)).  so it would clearer if id was named 'estimate_id' in the estimate table, and not 'id' (if that is what it is).  with many tables, hard to what 'id' means.